# wxListView in MOTIF doesn't refresh after scrolling

Tags: wxwidgets

I'm working with wxWidgets 2.8 on a MOTIF (sic) linux box.

I noticed that `wxListView` and `wxListCtrl` don't refresh correctly their content after a scroll. When I act on the scrollbar, the new items are invisible until I click on them.

The misbehaviour is present also in the sample "listctrl" that comes with the wxWidgets library.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: No real answer, just an advice to switch away from wxMotif, it hasn't been maintained for ages and ages and I'm very surprised that it still works at all. What platform still doesn't have GTK+ nowadays?

Comment: @VZ. Unless motif and gtk+ can coexist on the same Linux machine, I cannot switch away from wxMotif. I'm maintaining a wx app that must run on a industrial machine where other legacy motif applications are running. BTW: can coexist motif and gtk+ on the same machine?

Comment: Yes, they definitely can coexist.

Comment: @VZ. Really? Do you mean I can install GTK+ on a Linux box with motif and run wxGTK applications on it?! It would be great! Any pointer about installing GTK+?

Comment: Yes, really, this is not a problem at all and nothing special is needed to install GTK+, i.e. just do it in the usual way.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's a wxWidgets bug.

My first try was to work-around it by refreshing the `wxListView` after a scroll. Unfortunately, it seems wxWidgets doesn't provide scroll events for `wxListView`/`wxListCtrl`.

Finally, I solved my problem using the following `ListView` instead of `wxListView` in my code:

```
// listview.h

#ifndef LISTVIEW_H_
#define LISTVIEW_H_

#include <wx/listctrl.h>

class RefreshingListView : public wxListView, private wxTimer
{
public:
    RefreshingListView( wxWindow *parent, wxWindowID id, 
                        const wxPoint &pos=wxDefaultPosition, 
                        const wxSize &size=wxDefaultSize, 
                        long style=wxLC_ICON, 
                        const wxValidator &validator=wxDefaultValidator,
                        const wxString &name=wxListCtrlNameStr ) :
        wxListView( parent, id, pos, size, style, validator, name ),
        lastTopItem( GetTopItem() )
    {
        Start( 300 ); // ms
    }
    // override
    virtual void Notify() { CheckTopItem(); }
private:
    void CheckTopItem()
    {
        long it = GetTopItem();
        if ( it != lastTopItem )
        {
            Refresh();
            lastTopItem = it;
        }
    }
    long lastTopItem;
};

#ifdef __WXMOTIF__
    typedef RefreshingListView ListView;
#else
    typedef wxListView ListView;
#endif

#endif // LISTVIEW_H_
```

Maybe it can be useful to someone :-)